# UK Entry Stamp - different from a visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, passport-stamps

I've seen similar questions like this on the site before, but was wondering if anyone was able to point me to an official site that says that, as an American citizen traveling to the UK, the stamp put on my passport at the airport is an entry stamp and does NOT count as a visa.  Or, alternatively, a site that says the opposite.  Or has any real information about this, to be honest, I'm getting a bit desperate!

I know as an American citizen I do not need a visa to get into the UK as a tourist, but I need to know if the entry stamp counts as a visa given at the airport.  Basically, if you enter the UK for a short-term visit (just to see the country), are you given a visa at the airport?

Comment: Why do you need to know if it counts as a visa?

Comment: In fact, another user explained recently that UK law does not use the word “visa” at all. Instead, some people require an “entry clearance”. So if you don't explain what *you* mean by “visa” and what consequences you attach to this categorization, it will be difficult to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Relaxed, in context they don't use it for visitors at all. Entry Clearance and Entry Certificate are the legal terms used in the law.  There's still transit visas though, plus the PBS side.

Comment: @cpast - I need to know if visiting the UK as a tourist after living their on a student visa for several years means that the last visa I had was a tourist visa, not my student visa.

Comment: @Relaxed - I need it as defined but the UK government, for applying for a work visa.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I read the question differently.  In all events, I would be REAL CAREFUL with what the visa person told you. Get it in writing if possible, or double check with a proper UK solicitor.

Comment: @GayotFow - thank you again for all the information in your answer! I was worried for a moment that I'd offended you, hence the deletion.  I saw your background on your profile page, and I hope you don't mind if I ask for some more help from you - how do you suggest I should go forward? Can you recommend a (hopefully not too expensive) reliable UK immigration solicitor? I always hear there are a lot out to scam people. Or do you have any other suggestions for how I can find this out? I'm trying to get what I was told by the visa person told me in writing (an email), so we'll see. Thanks again!

Comment: No offence at all.  I don't take on casework any more, but you can call somebody like Sophie Barrett-Brown and ask for a phone consultation.  I would be VERY CAREFUL. Some Home Office person a year down the road may not see things the same way as the guy you spoke with.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll look her up and go from there. Visas have been my nightmare for several years now, so I totally believe that other people may not agree with the advice I got. I'd love to believe it's that easy though! I'll see what their email reply says (I submitted my question through the website, which might help, if they agree with the advice I got over the phone). Thank you again!

Comment: @UStoUK, select the most appropriate answer below and ACCEPT it.  That will bring the question to a professional conclusion.

Comment: @Relaxed Where's this other post? UK government's official department is called [UK Visas and Immigration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Visas_and_Immigration) although previously known as the "UK Border Agency" and even the official terminology on the [GOV.uk site uses "visas and immigration"](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I am thinking in particular about [this post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/what-does-the-acronym-eco-mean-in-discussions-of-visas/43270#43270). But you will indeed find the word “visa” in various places, in particular in information material for the public. Those are all rather informal uses of the word, it seems that they do not correspond to a specific, well-defined legal concept. And GayotFow provided another nuance in a comment above. By contrast Schengen regulations explicitly spell out what a visa is and never use any other word (like “entry clearance”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, a "visa at the airport" (or "the border") is something you pay for, and probably fill out an application form for.  A US citizen entering the UK as a general visitor does neither.

In addition, such a visa usually takes the form of a piece of paper stuck into the passport on one of the visa pages, not just an inked stamp.  There is no such piece of paper for US tourists in the UK.

I also note that the government site https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa says that a US citizen coming as a tourist "won't need a visa" -- they do not say that you have an implicit visa represented by the passport stamp or anything like that.  They say that you do not need a visa.  That implies that the passport stamp is not a visa.

Comment: Does that mean an American can stay as long as they want?

Comment: @GayotFow no, not at all.  The stamp limits their stay to 6 months, or at least that was the case 10 years ago or so, the last time I entered the UK on an American passport.  That's why I qualified with "coming as a tourist" -- for longer stays, US nationals would need a visa or resident permit or the like.

Comment: As pointed out in his comments, the OP is gaming a T2 application, presumably to evade the cooling off period. From a legal standpoint, someone receiving leave to enter has a visa.  Ask the IO next time you enter.  My answer was to a different question and has been deleted.  The OP is happy and all's well.

Comment: @pnuts sure.  Some countries give you a stamp at the border that says "visa." The UAE is apparently such a country.  The question is specifically tagged for the UK, though, so this answer should be read in that context.

Comment: @phoog Visas can be stamps, but they're *separate* stamps from the entry stamp. Oman being an example https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Oman_Visa_on_arrival.jpg

Answer (score 2):

A Visa is permission to enter a country.  An Entry Stamp is documentation that you did enter the country and on which date.  And conversely, an Exit Stamp is documentation that you left said country and on which date.

In general all foreign nationals get Entry Stamps, irregardless of whether a visa is required or not.

A Visa on Arrival is nothing more than a last minute opportunity to get a visa when your nationality requires it.  Once in your passport, you will still get an entry stamp acknowledging the date of entry.

So NO an entry stamp for a US citizen entering the UK is not a "visa".

Comment: Actually, a visa is not necessarily "permission to enter a country."  For example, the US describes a visa as "allow[ing] a foreign citizen to travel to a U.S. port-of-entry (generally an airport) and request permission to enter the United States."  It is not permission to enter the US.  Because of this, US visitors are not necessarily required to leave the country before the expiration of their visa.

Comment: What does a UK exit stamp look like? I've never seen one.

Comment: My intent was to describe the difference between a visa and entry stamp in GENERAL terms.  Each country will describe the visa definition differently.  And yes Gayot, the UK does not stamp you out, but many countries DO.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is certain: This entry stamp is much easier to obtain than a Schengen or US visa. You don't need to apply weeks in advance, attend an interview in some distant consulate, provide biometrics or pay tens of euros/dollars in fees.

Also, many people do need to go through a similar procedure to get what's called an “entry clearance” for the UK, which US citizens do not generally require.

In light of all this and by analogy, I would think that an entry stamp does not really “count” as a visa. But of course, things like the US ESTA and visa-on-arrival schemes kind of blur the distinction and if you don't tell us what *you* mean by “visa” and why it matters to you, it's impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: OP (UStoUK) here - I used to live in the UK under a student visa. Because I studied there, I get special exceptions when someone in the UK is hiring me and paying for my work visa as long as the last visa I was under is the student visa. After I left the UK as a student, I went back for a visit as a tourist and I need to know if that means I no longer get the special exceptions.  FWIW, I spoke to someone at the UK Visa Office and they have clarified that the entry stamp is NOT a visa, and it should be fine as long as I explain the above when applying.

Comment: @UStoUK Entering the UK as a general visitor does _not_ allow you to accept employment of any sort, and doing so - even if you can convince an employer to hire you by showing them your old student visa - is a great way to get deported and banned. You can work (within limitations) if you enter on a student visa, but you would have to actually be studying...

Comment: @MichaelHampton - thanks, don't worry, that's not the plan! I'll be applying for a Tier 2 work visa, I just need to know this information for my application

Answer (score 2):

The entry stamp is not a visa and although it is given a 6 month expiry date it actually expires the day you leave the UK so you can't return on this stamp. This is very important for people entering the UK as an EEE family resident, the Surindar Singh method of entry.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to back this up? Some sort of explanation of what the Surindar Singh method of entry is?