# How can I address ECO's concerns about my employment?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-employment

I am going to reapply UK Standard Visitor Visa. What should I add in employer's letter that can be acceptable to ECO?

- [Page 1 of my refusal letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cDTZ.jpg)
- [Page 2 of my refusal letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhV2P.jpg)

Comment: What's "ECO"? Should we have a tag for it? Oh: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/what-does-the-acronym-eco-mean-in-discussions-of-visas

Comment: @hippietrail If we had a tag "eco", people would use it mostly for environmental aspects of travel...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, your financials don't seem to make sense.

Your application says you earn PKR 78,000/month working for Punjab Beverage Company. Therefore, the ECO expects to see the same salary stated on the letter from your employer and he expects to see the same amount of money deposited into your bank account every month. Why is this not happening? If your income is actually irregular from "agricultural and cattle farming," why does your application say you earn this salary from Punjab Beverage Company? And if you do receive that salary from the Beverage Company, where is it going if not your bank account?

We have an answer here [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), which will tell you more about bank statements and what the ECO is looking to see from them.

Also, the ECO doesn't understand why your employer is promising to pay for the cost of your vacation. Normally, your employer would only pay for your trip if it was for business purposes.

Most importantly though, is the first paragraph. You applied previously, and the ECO found that "there is no evidence to show there has been any significant change in your circumstances since then." For a new application to be successful, you would need to show significantly different personal circumstances, such as greater ties to your home country. I would not apply again unless and until you are able to do so.

Comment: +1, but the OP is focused on the wrong thing! please remember that they got the OP *mainly* on change of circumstances (dot point 1) from his previous application.  The situation where the OP is going for a compassionate and the employer is paying is *strange* and probably related to his previous application also. Getting an employer's confirmation will not amount to the change of circumstances he needs to show.  In other words, he should save the £87 and not apply, and thus avoid a 3rd back-to-back refusal :)  Also, a great link in your answer :)

Comment: @GayotFow Great points. If you want to advise the OP not to advise again, that would be a useful answer too.

Comment: You have covered it, but it wouldn't hurt to mention that he's focused on a paragraph that is not the show-stopper :)

Comment: I mentioned 78000 as gross monthly salary on the form, my net monthly salary after deductions is 50,000. I earn this from Punjab beverages company. Apart from that I do have irregular agricultural income which I did not declare on my application. I have about 20,00000 in my personal bank account but I do not have formal evidence of that income. Shall I include this in my next application and explain why in Pakistan we do not have proper evidence in black and white.

Comment: My employer is willing to provide a revised employment letter explaining gross and net salary amounts and full breakdown of deductions. Also why they are meeting the full cost of my trip. They send their employees every year, I could not go during the last 3 years, my employer is willing to pay all the costs worth £3500. They do pay full cost of the trip for their senior employees. I do not think of anything else to explain why my employer is paying all costs of the trip. Can you advise what other reasons can be?

Comment: In my previous application back in Feb 2012, I was single, solely dependant on my parents, unemployed, sponsored by my brother in UK. This time I am independent, employed, engaged and planning to get married next year. These are the changes, are these counted as significant changes?

Comment: @aabbas, you asked your question and got your answer. This site is not designed to go on and on in comments raising new questions. If you have a new question about what constitutes a change of circumstances, ask a new question.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and mark this answer as 'accepted'