# I've told the immigration officer I'm staying in the UK for 1 month. Can I now change my departure date to leave at a later time?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm now in the UK with a Standard Tourist Visa (valid for six months until August) for my graduation ceremony and a holiday. I arrived here on the 10th of Feb and planned on leaving on the 10th of March (so I'd stay here for a month). I've written the date of my intended departure date on the immigration (arrival card) and the officer took the card when she interviewed me at the airport and then let me enter. Unfortunately three days after my graduation I caught a cold and it triggered my asthma. I was sick for over a week. Considering this, I'm thinking of extending my stay until end of this month. But I'm worried if this is allowed. Considering that I've already put my departure date in the immigration/arrival card.

If I did extend, should I inform the immigration? And if so, would this be a problem the next time I visit the country?

Comment: Be sure to read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79986/uk-visa-refusal-on-credibility-grounds-longer-visit-than-originally-described

Comment: I will just give a _personal_ opinion while you wait for an answer. My take is that many consular officers, **particularly** the UK and USA are looking for an opportunity to deny you a visa for any material cause. For the average person, a cold does not cause a person to postpone travel by one month. If you got asthma, and it is bad, make sure you have documentation from seeing a physician indicating the seriousness. My best friend has very bad asthma, a bad bout leaves him weak for maximum a week. You're treading dangerous water if you double the length of your intended stay.

Comment: @GayotFow Isn't it a full duplicate?

Comment: @JonathanReez on 2nd read, yes it is

Comment: Whilst I'm also worried about future visa application, but what I was asking in my question is about my next visit in the near future using the same visa. Also whether it is allowed to extend my stay just for a few more days. I know initially I've mentioned about extending until end of month, but I realise this would be a stretch. So I've been considering about extending for three days until the 12. The post that you referred to me stated that the person extended their stay from 2 weeks to 2 or 3 months, which was obviously a lot longer than they had originally planned.