# Change return ticket date

Tags: uk, brazilian-citizens

Please, I have a 6 month leave to enter and when I arrived, I've showed a return ticket for the next week. Now I'd like to stay for 15 days more. Should I inform that to autorities? Thank you very much.

Comment: For clarity, what is your citizenship, how long did you originally plan to stay and how long have you already spent in the UK in the last 12 months?

Comment: I'm from Brazil, never been to the UK before. My first plan was to stay for 2 weeks. I spent 10 days and now I'd like to stay one more month. Thanks.

Comment: It is legal for you to stay longer and there is no requirement to inform Immigration. However, if you told the Immigration officer when you arrived that you would stay for two weeks, more than doubling the length of your stay could create problems for you on later visits. The next time you try to enter the UK visa-free, you may be questioned about what caused you to change your plans, and you could be refused entry if they don't like your answer.

Comment: Of course, you are aware that you are not allowed to work while you are in the UK? So the question of how you are going to support yourself for an entire additional month arises.

Answer (score 5):

You’re allowed to stay until the time you were given upon entry, usually six months. You do not have to notify immigration.

Note however that changing your duration of stay significantly can make you appear unreliable or dishonest and subsequent visa applications may be denied.

If it is your first visit to the United Kingdom, it is better to stick to that duration you gave them officially. They are even sometimes denying people visa renewals for staying shorter than they indicated in their visa applications.

Comment: Do you have a source for saying that the UK is denying visas to people who visit for less time than originally planned? I’ve seen many questions on TSE about problems caused by extending visits, but don’t recall any about the opposite.

Comment: @Traveller see [Can departing earlier than scheduled cause problems with UK Immigration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/98812/19400)

Comment: @Phoog Thanks, hadn’t seen that one. I guess the overall risk profile is what influences decisions. My own partner, who comes from a third world country and depends on me for financial sponsorship, has visited the UK three times in the last four years. The first two times he extended his stay by one month; his third visit visa application this year was approved without problems and he arrived/departed on the date we stated in the application. He was interviewed by Immigration on arrival each time but was allowed to enter.

Comment: Actually, he is from one of the countries named in the Guardian news article referenced in the question.