# Sponsorship visa to the UK

Tags: visas, uk

My girlfriend is based in the UK, a single mom of two little girls, working class, has her place etc.

We have been dating since April 2017. She visited Nigeria in October to see my family, with which she spent a week. So I plan to visit her family and formally introduce myself. She said she will be my sponsor and she would apply for the visa for me from the UK. We are both 33 years old. My account has 1,500 pounds after conversion. Please what steps do we need to take to ensure my application is successful? Plus I currently work for a well-known telecom company in Nigeria. What do we both need to get a successful application.

Comment: She can't apply for a visa for you - you're an adult and must apply for your  visa yourself. You can include the details of her sponsorship in your application.

Comment: Nobody on the internet can give you a guarantee of successful application.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: Prepare your case documents in an watertight manner. Your case will raise the red flag, in most cases, considering the reports of fraud marriages to gain British citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated in the comments, you must make the application, not your sponsor.

The money you have available to you is of secondary importance. What is absolutely critical is that you can convince the entry clearance officer that you will return home after your trip. They start with the presumption that you won't. You must include as much evidence as possible of your employment, since this can counter the ECO's assumption that you will overstay.

Therefore, you should include a letter from your employer detailing your position, salary, length of service etc. and stating that your trip is authorized.

You should include as many bank statements as you can, showing that you regularly receive your salary, and that you are building up savings. [There is an excellent answer here explaining how the ECO will interpret your bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105). Don't be tempted to have friends or family transfer you extra funds, since this will look like "funds parking", and could lead the ECO to believe you are lying.

Do not be tempted to take too long a trip. People with jobs don't usually take long holidays (longer than two weeks). A long trip will cause the ECO to doubt that you have a stable job. Do not fall into the trap of staying longer than you say you will. If your visa is granted, you may receive a visa for a longer time than you asked for. Regardless, you should return home on the day that you said you would. Doing otherwise [could lead to future visa applications being refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79986/uk-visa-refusal-on-credibility-grounds-longer-visit-than-originally-described/79989#79989).

As [the government guidance states](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) you must also supply an itinerary, where you will stay, and how much you think it will cost.

Even if you do everything right, you may still be unable to overcome the presumption that you will overstay. In this case, it will be fruitless to reapply unless you have extremely convincing new evidence to the contrary, or your circumstances change (for example, you get a promotion or a raise). You could consider meeting your girlfriend's family somewhere outside the UK, where there will be less of a  presumption that you are trying to come to live with her.

Comment: OK noted, I would further like to ask this too.  Firstly i have no saving account, i earn about 98 000 naira working for a telecom company for over 5 years now, Concerning funds parking, I sold my car for about 850 000 naira first week of February and the money was paid in my salary account, that's the only account I have. I transfered a 100 000naira to my sibling and 95 000naira to my cousin, I'm trying to spread the money out so it don't look like I'm money parking. I want to activate an account now and transfer the rest of the money there bit by bit, its has been dormant for a longtime.

Comment: must I wait 6months before I can present it? is that a good idea?? Please I will truly appreciate your advice and can I state I'm spending 3 weeks in the UK with a week of unpaid salary because two weeks may not be enough to visit her entire family? Please I need your advice. Thank you guys

Comment: Unfortunately, selling your car makes your situation worse, not better. The ECO will wonder why you've sold your car. It makes it look as if you are leaving the country permanently (unless you can credibly explain why you don't need a car anymore). Three weeks seems like a long trip to me. If you start out applying for shorter trips, and return home as promised, you're more likely to be granted a visa for longer stays in future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good and quick answer to the question presented in the body:

> Please what steps do we need to take to ensure my application is successful?

This answer is: get represented by an [immigration lawyer or solicitor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89170/43483). It will be costly but the benefit will likely be acquiring the desired visa. Regulated solicitors are required by law to refuse cases in which they see no chance of success, so they will be able to tell you how to approach the issue.

My layman’s understanding — that I have outlined in the answer under your other question — is that your case is very, very far in ‘complex’ territory and getting represented is very strongly advised.